# Script to Find & Replace cells that CONTAIN a certain value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, replace, find, regexp-replace

Since Macros do NOT actually record the "Find and Replace" action, I am trying to get a script to find and replace certain strings that can be found in several cells. For example; I have a cell containing "Fred and Joe" and I need to get rid of the "and". In another cell, I may have "Fred, Joe" and I need to get rid of the ",".

I have tried the below, but it only works when the cell ONLY contains "AND". I need the script to ALSO replace the value when the cell CONTAINS the "var f":

```
}
function FandR(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = sh.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var f = "and";
  var r = ",";
  var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  Logger.log(data.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < data[0].length;i++){
    for (var j = 0; j < data.length;j++){
      if(data[j][i]==f)
      ss.getRange(j+1,i+1).setValue(r);
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with _when the cell CONTAINS the "var f"_? Are you referring to the actual string 'var f'? In that case, you should simply replace `if(data[j][i]==f)` with `if(data[j][i]==f || data[j][i]=='var f')`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response :-)
What I mean is that the "and" should be replaced by "" even when the cell contains other characters.
By replacing that line of code I am not getting the expected result. The script is only replacing cells containing ONLY "and" but not those containing "and" and other characters...

Comment: Hi @Marc, in that case you should use `indexOf()` in order to check that the cell _contains_ the string rather than `==` (which checks if the cell value _is equal to_ the string); I posted the code as an answer.

Comment: @secan please don't tag questions [tag:vba] that are clearly not containing VBA code. This is google-apps-script code (a kind of JavaScript). Also the tag [tag:macros] must not to be used for scripting languages like VBA as the tag description says. I fixed the tags to more suitable ones.

Answer (score 1):

Following you further clarification, I think what you need is:

```
function FindReplaceMacro() {
  /*
   * Create a regular expression to match
   *   - the string 'and' surrounded by spaces (' and ', ' AND ')
   *   - any non-alphabetic character surrounded by spaces (e.g. ' - ', ' / ', etc.)
   *   - a comma followed by a space (', ')
   */
  var re = / and | \W |, /gi;
  
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  
  for (var r = 0; r < values.length; r++) {
    for (var c = 0; c < values[r].length; c++) {
      sheet.getRange(r+1, c+1).setValue(values[r][c].replace(re, ' '));
    }
  }
}
```

You can test it [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HwRrFXxVAJ4PcFVNhe_B7TP1-ObFoLPncFLm9G-bOZk/edit#gid=0) (you might need to refresh the page after the macro execution, in order to see the modified data)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed!!!!!!
Thanks so much :-)

Comment: @Marc, pay attention as I modified the code in order _not_ to replace "and" when it is inside a word (e.g. "cANDidate"); I assume that is the behaviour you want ;)

Comment: Hi @secan.
When I paste the code including the Regex I am getting the error: ReferenceError: RegEx is not defined.
    When I use the previous code, the "and" are replaced by "," but I am still getting an error: TypeError: data[j][i].indexOf is not a function. 
     I also was wondering how I can add more values to be replaced for "," (and, &, +, -, plus"...

Comment: Mmmh... I've never worked with macros but, from a quick research, apparently you have to use VBA, which is a bit different from JavaScript; [this article](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/regex/) should cover the differences relevant to your case, for what concerns regular expression, while [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function) you can see how to use the `InStr()` function, which is VBA equivalent of `indexOf()`.

Comment: By the way, there was a typo (now amended) in my code: it is `RegExp` not `RegEx`

Comment: Thanks @secan again for your answer. I feel dumb but I am not managing to get this working. Maybe with a "test" file I explain myself better.  What I am doing (ultimately) is getting a list of "orders" in a column. The issue I face is that the number of orders is huge and they contain this "connecting" words/symbols such as "and, +, -, ,, &". My objective is to get rid of them so that I can then split data into columns and with a "UNIQUE" formula get a list of unique orders I have received: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HwRrFXxVAJ4PcFVNhe_B7TP1-ObFoLPncFLm9G-bOZk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi @Marc, apologies for the delay in my answer but I was quite busy yesterday. I updated the code in my answer and tested it; it should be what you are looking for.